# How to read two files in a nested loop in Unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

My objective here is to read each revision present in `revisions.txt` and extract the text against that revision number from `logs.txt` file.

For example `revisions.txt` file has the following inputs,

- APP-1001
- APP-1002
- APP-1004

And `logs.txt` file has the following inputs,

- APP-999 : Bug Fix for XYZ issues
- APP-1001 : Bug Fix for XYZ issues
- APP-1002 : Bug Fix for XYZ issues
- APP-1003 : Bug Fix for XYZ issues
- APP-1004 : Bug Fix for XYZ issues

I want to get all the lines against all revisions in the `revisions.txt` file. I came up with the following code,

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Start!"
input=logs.txt
revision=revisions.txt

IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a revs < $revision

for rev in "${revs[@]}"
do
    echo $rev
    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
       regex='^'$rev'(.*)'
       if [[ $line =~ $regex ]];
       then
          echo $line
       fi
    done < "$input"
done
```

**Output** as of now,
APP-1001
APP-1002
APP-1004
APP-1004 : Bug Fix for XYZ issues

It's only printing text for the last revision i.e. APP-1004. I read on the web that it's not possible to read two files in nested loop.

Please suggest a different way of doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for `grep -f revisions.txt logs.txt`?

Comment: @WilliamPursell this is simple task. I am doing multiple things in second file once i get the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest the loops and hence, you can iterate from both files at the same time.

```
while read revisions_line
do
    while read logs_line
    do

        echo "This line comes from revisions : $revisions_line"
        echo "This line comes from logs : $logs_line"

    done << "$(  cat logs.txt)"
done << "$(  cat revisions.txt)"
```

Regards!

Comment: i am getting following errors, `./filter2.sh: line 18: warning: here-document at line 15 delimited by end-of-file (wanted '$(cat svn2.txt)')
./filter2.sh: line 19: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: @JBaba Were you able to resolve your problems? If not please post the code, Ill take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use below script for the same:-

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
   #echo "$line logs.txt"
   log_info=$(grep $line logs.txt)
   if [ log_info != "" ]; then
      echo "$log_info" | awk '{$1=$2=""; print $0}' | sed 's/^[ \t]*//'
   fi
done < revisions.txt
```

How will it work? While loop will read each line from file `revisions.txt` and `grep` will search for that in `logs.txt` file and if found it will store that line in variable `log_info`. Now if `log_info` variable is not empty the line will be redirect to `awk` command and `awk` command will remove column1 and column2 from the line and redirect the output to `sed` command and finally `sed` will remove the leading blank space from it. The final out put will be:-

```
Bug Fix for XYZ issues
Bug Fix for XYZ issues
Bug Fix for XYZ issues
```

If you want the whole string just modify like below:-

```
 echo "$log_info"
```

If you don't bother about the leading blank space you can go ahead with below:-

```
echo "$log_info" | awk '{$1=$2=""; print $0}'
```

Comment: You are just reading one line here. I have to read multiple lines/iterate right after i found the match in `logs.txt` file in an inner loop.